# Most efficient merging of 2 text files.

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, java-io

So I have large (around 4 gigs each) txt files in pairs and I need to create a 3rd file which would consist of the 2 files in shuffle mode. The following equation presents it best:

3rdfile = (4 lines from file 1) + (4 lines from file 2) and this is repeated until I hit the end of file 1 (both input files will have the same length - this is by definition). Here is the code I'm using now but this doesn't scale very good on large files. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this - would working with memory mapped file help ? All ideas are welcome.

```
public static void mergeFastq(String forwardFile, String reverseFile, String outputFile) {

    try {
        BufferedReader inputReaderForward = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(forwardFile));
        BufferedReader inputReaderReverse = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(reverseFile));
        PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true));

        String forwardLine = null;
        System.out.println("Begin merging Fastq files");
        int readsMerge = 0;
        while ((forwardLine = inputReaderForward.readLine()) != null) {

            //append the forward file
            outputWriter.println(forwardLine);
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderForward.readLine());
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderForward.readLine());
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderForward.readLine());
            //append the reverse file
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderReverse.readLine());
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderReverse.readLine());
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderReverse.readLine());
            outputWriter.println(inputReaderReverse.readLine());

            readsMerge++;
            if(readsMerge % 10000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("[" + now() + "] Merged 10000");
                readsMerge = 0;
            }

        }

        inputReaderForward.close();
        inputReaderReverse.close();
        outputWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while merging FastQ files", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you use a bash script or do you need to use java?

Comment: Don't you need to check for `null` for the other three lines after `outputWriter.println(forwardLine);`?

Comment: Your question sounds as if your file size is fix. If your line size is also fix or you know the byte representation of your new line character you could read and write as bytes instead of characters which would save the time used for character de/encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you also want to try to use a BufferedWriter to cut down your file IO operations.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html

Comment: but since I'm using println() this would case a flush of the underlying buffer everytime.

Comment: Ok, then also set `autoFlush` to `false` in your `PrintWriter`

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer is to use a bigger buffer, which help to reduce to total number of I/O call being made.

Usually, memory mapped IO with FileChannel (see Java NIO) will be used for handling large data file IO. In this case, however, it is not the case, as you need to inspect the file content in order to determine the boundary for every 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Buffer your read and write operations. Buffer needs to be large enough to minimize the read/write operations and still be memory efficient. This is really simple and it works.

```
void write(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[102400]; //optimize the size of buffer to your needs
    int num;
    while((n = is.read(buf)) != -1){
        os.write(buffer, 0, num);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I just realized that you need to shuffle the lines, so this code will not work for you as is but, the concept still remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

If performance was the main requirement, then I would code this function in C or C++ instead of Java.

But regardless of language used, what I would do is try to manage memory myself. I would create two large buffers, say 128MB or more each and fill them with data from the two text files. Then you need a 3rd buffer that is twice as big as the previous two. The algorithm will  start moving characters one by one from input buffer #1 to destination buffer, and at the same time count EOLs. Once you reach the 4th line you store the current position on that buffer away and repeat the same process with the 2nd input buffer. You continue alternating between the two input buffers, replenishing the buffers when you consume all the data in them. Each time you have to refill the input buffers you can also write the destination buffer and empty it.

Comment: Why C/C++?  If properly written, this should be I/O bound in either language.  Why would it be faster?

Comment: Regardless of language used, this algorithm would be I/O bound only if you used asynchronous I/O and you can process buffers faster than it takes to read and write them. None of the replies so far suggest such an approach (maybe I should write another answer!)

Comment: We must mean different things by I/O bound.  I mean "performance is dominated by waiting for input and output".  Given the negligible amount of processing involved in a well-designed program to do this job, I would expect that to be the case here.  Making I/O asynchronous would, if anything, make it less I/O bound, not more - that's the reason to do it.

Comment: My point was that I/O is blocked while CPU does its thing, so the process is also CPU bound. For the process to be strictly I/O bound you need to paralelize the CPU work (i.e. counting EOLs) and have it run concurrently with I/O.

Comment: Virtually any modern operating system is heavily buffered for both reading and writing (with smart pre-fetching for sequential reads).  Ditto, sometimes, for disk controllers, and to a limited extent, even the drives themselves.  The threads that do the actual I/O are outside of the JVM - they're in the OS itself.  I/O is _not_ blocked - the disk is busy - as long as it has something to do.  So no, it's not CPU bound unless badly written.

Comment: if what you say is true, the reading line by line or reading big chunks would make little difference, yet I'm sure it will have a big improvement. The fact is, buffering and caching in the OS helps only up to some point, the caching strategy is not aggresive enough, you can do a lot better on your own because you know what is the access pattern for your application.

Comment: Independent of I/O costs, reading line-by-line increases CPU usage greatly by requiring a call into the OS for each line.  The data may be all cached up, but if it's gotten a teaspoonful at a time, a lot of useless time is spent context-switching into the kernel, et al.